# Is there a matrix with 0 "ultimate maximum"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

## Definitions

Let's define the $\operatorname{argmax}$ for a finite sequence $(a_i)$ as $\operatorname{argmax}(a_i) = \min(\{j| a_j=\max(a_i)\})$, i.e. the first index where $(a_i)$ attains it's maximum.

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix. We call the $(i,j)$ pair an "ultimate maximum" of $A$ if $\operatorname{argmax}(A_{.,j})=i$ and $\operatorname{argmax}(A_{i,.})=j$, i.e. the $\operatorname{argmax}$ of the $i$-th row is $j$ and the $\operatorname{argmax}$ of the $j$-th row is $i$.

## Example

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1\,2\,3 \\
4\,5\,6
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then the $\operatorname{argmax}$ of both of the rows is $3$, and the $\operatorname{argmax}$ of all of the columns is $2$, so $A$ has one "ultimate maximum": $(2, 3)$

## Motivation

I'm examining the time evolution of a system. The probability of the $j$-th particle in the previous moment being the same as the $i$-th now is proportional to $A_{i, j}$. So if  $(i, j)$ is an "ultimate maximum" of $A$, then I can safely say that they are the same. But for this to work, I'd need every matrix to have at least $1$ "ultimate maximum".

## The matrix elements

The elements of the matrices I'm interested in are positive real numbers (including $0$).

## My work

I wasn't able to find a matrix with $0$ "ultimate maximum". I tested $4$ different cases numerically, with $1,000,000$ matrices in each case:

- $100 \times 100$ matrices with random elements from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
- $50 \times 300$ matrices with random elements from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
- $100 \times 100$ matrices with normally distributed random elements
- $50 \times 300$ matrices with normally distributed random elements

But all of them had at least $1$ "ultimate maximum".

Comment: Well as long as at least one row and column has a defined $\operatorname{argmax}$ then a matrix has an ultimate maximum right? And you can use some variant of the well ordering principle to prove that, probably.

Comment: @Kyky Sorry for the late reply. Every row and column has an $\operatorname{argmax}$, but I don't know if at least one of them coincide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed each matrix has an "ultimate maximum".

Let $m$ be the maximum value of the matrix overall. In particular there must be a row in which $m$ occurs: let $i$ be the first row in which $m$ occurs. Now the value $m$ must occur in row $i$: let $j$ be the first column such that $A_{i, j} = m$.

Now let us show that $(i, j)$ is an ultimate maximum.

1. If there were an $i'$ such that $i' < i$ and $A_{i', j} \geq m$, then $A_{i', j} = m$ (since $m$ is the maximum of $A$), but this contradicts $i$ being the first row in which $m$ occurs. Thus $i = \mathrm{argmax}(A_{\cdot, j})$.
2. If there were a $j'$ such that $j' < j$ yet $A_{i, j'} \geq m$, then again we would need to have $A_{i, j'} = m$, but this contradicts that $j$ was the first column for which $A_{i, j} = m$. Thus $j = \mathrm{argmax}(A_{i, \cdot})$.

Comment: Thank you! I feel a little bit stupid now :) I need to wait at least 24 hour before awarding you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Color all $1\times1$ squares that are filled with the greatest number appearing in the whole table. Now take an arbitrary colored square. Name the chosen square in each moment as "Current square" and execute the following algorithm until it's over:
$i)$ If there exists at least one colored square in the same row with the "Current square" in it's left hand side, then take the leftmost colored square of that row as the next "Current square" and then repeat $(i)$. If there wasn't another colored square in the same row and in its left hand side, go to $(ii)$.
$ii)$ If there exists at least one colored square in the same column with the "Current square" upside it, then take the upmost colored square of that column as the next "Current square" and go to $(i)$. If there wasn't another colored square in the same column and upside it, finish.
Clearly the algorithm is finite and when you reach a final square that is the ultimate maximum of its row and column and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Mees de Vries was the first to answer so I feel like the fair act is to award them, but I do appreciate your answer as well!

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest we said the same thing but he wrote it way clearer than what I said in addition to the fact that he was the first